# Fadein-Effect only working on one Page

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner when it comes to coding in HTML and CSS and encountered a problem that drives me nuts. I did an intense research of course but couldn´t find a solution to my problem:

I created a fadein Effect on pageload via CSS that only works on one page in Internet Explorer and Edge, not on others although it´s exactly the same code applied upfront to all pages.

CSS:

```
/* KEYFRAMES fadeIn */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
body {
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: #FFF;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn ease-in 1;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn ease-in 1;
  animation: fadeIn ease-in 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2.5s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 2.5s;
  animation-duration: 2.5s;
}
```

As I said, this only works on one page, not on the others. All other browsers do the fadein perfectly fine on every page, so I assume it is an IE/Edge issue. On the HTML-side everything is the same, except for the content between the body-tags. I also have only one CSS file linked to my pages that contain this fadein-effect, so there should be no "doubled animations" coming into conflict or so. I hope someone has a solution for this.

Comment: Have you checks clearing your cache or adding `?randomnumber` after your CSS url?

Comment: Hello, clearing the cache did not solve the problem. I don´t know what you mean by ?randomnumber after my css url (I am a beginner, sorry).

Comment: @saesch_coder: Like this <link rel="stylesheet" href="your-style.css?123135"

Comment: Thanks, didn´t know about that, added ?12345 as suggested - no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works with me. Be sure to empty the cache.

If your a beginner, be sure to open the correct file in other browser. Check your URL.

It may sound silly, but when I starded coding, several times I did this mistake.

Comment: <!doctype html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My Title</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="portfolio/imgs/my_icon.ico"  />
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portfolio/landing-page.css">

</head>

<body>
 <video preload="auto" controls poster="portfolio/imgs/poster-video.jpg"
    <source src="portfolio/my-video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
    
    
 <a href="portfolio/index.html"><div id="Enter">Enter</div></a> <!-- END Enter -->    
    
</body>
</html>

Comment: Sorry I don´t know how to comment in "code-style" as I did with my starting post.

Comment: Doesn't matters ;). Are you sure that your css is loaded ? Try again in Chrome. If it's don't work again, open up the console wiith F12, and click on "Console". It should have errors, copy-paste them in a new comment.

Comment: Yes I am sure, all my styles are applied, for example font type and size, hover-effects and so on. Only the fadein fails. I give clearing the browser cache a try. By the way we are talking about going into browser settings and clearing the cache from there right?

Comment: That's really weird... There no errors message in console tab ? Do a screenshot of your "console" tab et the "element" tab and send it in comment if you can.

Comment: Oh, maybe try to put your keyframes after the body : body{
/*Your body css*/
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }

Comment: Console shows no errors. I solved this weird issue with a little "workarround" by creating a "if-IE-tag" and made a css-file only for this browser. Then I put my animation inside * { } this did the trick for IE. Basically this should work for all browser but however in Firefox this gives me another weird effect, meaning a close button I created in the upper right corner wasn´t clickable anymore. Thats why I came up with a IE-specific css-file. Is there a way to target only edge like "if-edge-tag"? Because it still doesnt work in edge.

Comment: There is a css hacks for Firefox :
@-moz-document url-prefix()
{
    tag {
        /*Put your code here*/
    }
}
For Edge, try this :

@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
  .selector { property:value; } 
}

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem now by doing the following:
1. Did an if-IE-tag, created specific IE-css-file and put animation inside

```
*{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;  
-webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
-moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
-o-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
-ms-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
animation:fadeIn ease-in 1; 
-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
-moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
-o-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
-ms-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
animation-fill-mode:forwards; 
-webkit-animation-duration:2.5s;
-moz-animation-duration:2.5s;
-o-animation-duration:2.5s;
-ms-animation-duration:2.5s;
animation-duration:2.5s;
}
```

Like so. Also in the overall "main" css I put

```
*{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;  
-ms-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1; 
-ms-animation-fill-mode:forwards;   
-ms-animation-duration:2.5s;    
}
```

When leaving this step out, IE won´t animated, who knows why... I targeted Edge in the main css by doing this

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {  
*{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;  
-webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
-webkit-animation-duration:2.5s;    
}
}
```

Now everything works as supposed. Of course I could have just used the main css for all browsers but however this had bad effects on Firefox on just one button not working anymore. I don´t know why but after tons of research and trys this did the trick. Thanks for everyone trying to help. Very nice and straight to the point Community here!